# How to cache another site iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, caching, iframe

My website load an iframe from another website. I would like to cache this iframe and than load a cache copy.

Unfortunately I can't use nginx, that's why I'm interesting how to cache iframe using php / js / ajax / xml or something other.

Maybe something like:

```
 - create iframe.php file on server with loading another site iframe
 - iframe.php load iframe first time, than cache it
 - include iframe.php where I need (but I don't 
understand how to save all native header information of another site)
```

All this I need to load header information from another website, but I can't do it many times, and need to load it once than show cache for new users.

Thx for any help!

Answer (score 1):

On the client side you cannot influence the cache behavior of the navigator for a third party page.

If you want to cache the page on the server side, the server side script must fetch the page and cache it. Your iframe must load this script.

I hope I answered your question. Unfortunately it is not quite clear to me .

Answer (score 1):

what about [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) ? **save** as .html to your hosting account and then load in iframe.

Comment: Remember that when you use iFrames, your page renders first and then the iFrame page will load, so your users see something all the time. If you're loading a heavy page via `file_get_contents()`, your page won't render until the content has been fully loaded and, if their server/network/script is slow, it's your users that will suffer as your page won't render until the PHP has finished.

Comment: I mean, save as cached / static file in server, then load in iframe. Auto update this file using cron.

Comment: checked it 
`$homepage = file_get_contents('https://other-site.com'); `

`echo $homepage;`
- works fine but not save any header information like cookies and other

Comment: Yes, a cron job will do the trick. But, what about images and scripts? If images on the third-party site have relative URL's (../images/1.png), they won't load when you inject the iFrame with HTML, as the image paths were relevent to their server, not yours. @RastWishes - make sure you're getting all images/css/javascript correctly.

Comment: @RastWishes: You also have to consider that the content owner may block your IP for scraping their data. They may also not be very happy about traffic being stolen from them. With live iFrames, the third-party owner gets one page view to your one page view. If you scrape their data to populate your own iFrame, they don't get any page views, but you're happy stealing and showing their creative work on your site. If it was my content you were scraping and traffic you were pinching, I would sew you. There is a lot to consider when using this suggestion.